# What does this index out of bounds error mean?

Tags: java

What does -1 mean in this error code?

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

Comment: That you've tried to access an array position that does not exist. For example, if the array has 10 elements (positions 0 to 9), and you try to use the 11th position, or less than 0 (which seems like the -1 in this case), you are out of bounds.

Answer (score 3):

Per the [Java Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html), an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is *"thrown to indicate that an array has been accessed with an illegal index. The index is either negative or greater than or equal to the size of the array."*

This usually occurs when you try to access an element of an array that does not exist. Consideer the following example:

```
String[] items = {"One", "Two"};
System.out.println(items[3]);
```

This will throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because there is no `items[3]` element.

---

Since you've not posted any code, we cannot help with your specific situation, but this should lead you in the right direction.

Comment: This is the line it is take from JButton button = board[x + offset][y]; There is too much code to put the rest on here.

Comment: Then I suggest you read the help section on how to provide a [mcve]. In many cases, the process of creating the MCVE will help you discover the error anyway.

Comment: There are literally an infinite number of reasons you could receive this error. We have no idea what `board` or `x` or `offset` or `y` might be.

Answer (score 2):

The index out of bounds means you have tried to get something from an array or list with an invalid index. The -1 is most likely the index you gave it. An array or list will never have an index of -1 be valid.